# Do snakes try to get in hammocks?

Tags: snakes, hammock

I use an [ENO hammock](https://www.eaglesnestoutfittersinc.com/) when I camp and I have always wondering if a snake would want to slither into my hammock while I'm sleeping. Note that this hammock is open, as opposed to a [Hennessy hammock](http://hennessyhammock.com/), which is enclosed with a bug net.

Is this a reasonable concern? Do snakes want to climb trees and webbing straps to get into a warm hammock?

Comment: Hammocks are typically what you sleep in to avoid snakes.

Comment: You may have a look on [this](https://www.hammockforums.net/forum/showthread.php/11498-Snakes-in-hammocks)

Comment: @Erik Texas, though I don't think Amazonian snakes behave differently from Alaskan snakes? Do you mean it depends on the weather?

Comment: @Erik Well that's terrifying. I know snakes like to crawl under tents because it's warm, so I was wondering if they try to climb the tree and hammock straps to get to a warm hammock.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/C7zGLB8h.gif

Comment: I don't know, but I recently found that a tree frog had taken up residence in the stuff stack I left hanging on the suspension straps overnight.

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find an authoritative reference to state that a snake wouldn't do that. The main climbing snake in Texas is the [Rat Snake](http://www.austinreptileservice.net/txrat.html). While one of those *could* climb into your hammock to cuddle, *I doubt* they would. At the end of the day it is **much easier** for a snake to slither into a sleeping bag/tent/boot/etc. than a hammock. Those items are all on the ground, and therefore easily encounter-able. It would have to be a pretty smart and determined snake to slither along the ground, sense your body heat above them, climb the tree, [slackline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slacklining) the hammock's webbing just to cuddle. Given that and what [ShemSeger](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/4148/shemseger) said in the comments:

> Hammocks are typically what you sleep in to avoid snakes.

**Overall I think you're safe in your hammock**, but if your buddies see this post expect to have a rubber snake slipped into your hammock next camping trip.

Comment: And, remember, the beauty of the hammock is that the PATH they TAKE to GET to you is very indirect (up the tree, down the line, etc.)